# Monitoring go application net/http metrics using prometheus

Tags: http, go, prometheus

I am developing an application in Go which uses the net/http package to make a number of external http requests/calls which I would like to monitor the http calls' latency, response times, status code etc.

As there are a number of endpoints which my applications calls, and there could be more that will be added in the future, I would like to consider a solution which will obtain the metrics for all such external http calls.

Any suggestions, guidance or examples on this is much appreciated.
I am thinking of some way in which a middleware/wrapper is added onto the Do/Raw call within the net/http package which I can create and modify a copy of but I'm not exactly sure how to do that.

Comment: One (!) way to do this is to abstract e.g. `http.Client` and `http.Request` and related functionality into your own type/methods. The abstraction would bind all outgoing requests to Prometheus such that, when your app does the equivalent of `client.Do()`, the underlying request will also populate a set of metrics. Commonly you'd also add e.g. tracing and logging too.

Comment: Does that mean I copy and modify my own net/http library ? Any example on how the modification could be done? Because I wanted it to sorted by the url and method called.

Comment: @KalaindeV Nope. Two options: You could simply write a helper method which takes the original request and increases a counter/starts a timer with a tag `target` containing the target URL. Or, you implement a [custom roundtripper for the http client](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Client) doing pretty much the same.

Comment: any example how this could be done?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very (!) **basic** example that abstracts `http.Client`'s `Do` method with a Prometheus `Counter` that `Inc`'s on every `Do` and labels the `Counter` with the host's name, the request method and the response code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "time"

    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"
    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promhttp"
)

type Client struct {
    Client  *http.Client
    Counter *prometheus.CounterVec
}

func NewClient(counter *prometheus.CounterVec) *Client {
    return &Client{
        Client:  &http.Client{},
        Counter: counter,
    }
}

func (c *Client) Do(rqst *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    resp, err := c.Client.Do(rqst)

    host := rqst.URL.Host
    code := strconv.Itoa(resp.StatusCode)
    c.Counter.With(prometheus.Labels{
        "host":          host,
        "response_code": code,
    }).Inc()

    return resp, err
}
func main() {

    metric := prometheus.NewCounterVec(
        prometheus.CounterOpts{
            Name: "foo",
            Help: "Number of HTTP requests.",
        },
        []string{
            "host",
            "response_code",
        },
    )
    prometheus.MustRegister(metric)

    c := NewClient(metric)

    go func() {
        for {
            method := http.MethodPost
            url := "https://httpbin.org/post"
            rqst, _ := http.NewRequest(method, url, nil)
            _, _ = c.Do(rqst)
            time.Sleep(15 * time.Second)
        }
    }()

    log.Println("Starting server")
    http.Handle("/metrics", promhttp.Handler())
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

And:

````
# HELP foo Number of HTTP requests.
# TYPE foo counter
foo{host="httpbin.org",method="POST",response_code="200"} 6```
````